# Format Date into mysql format

Tags: android, mysql, json, datepicker, textview

I'm working on a registration form that has a date picker. When a user selects a date, a TextView updates showing the selected date in the format (MM-dd-YYYY). When the user clicks the submit button it passes the forms data into a mysql db. It obviously doesn't insert the date because its not in the proper format of (yyyy-MM-dd). I tried using SimpleDateFormat method, but cannot get it to work. Can someone help me understand how to format the date?

```
datedob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reg_dob);

String dob = datedob.getText().toString();
```

My datepicker code:

```
public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    datedob = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.reg_dob);
    datedob.setText(month + "-" + day + "-" + year);
}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need two `DateFormat` instances:

- one to parse the date string from your `TextView`.
- one to format the parsed date to the desired representation.

That would look somewhat like this, assuming your `TextView` contains a `"MM-dd-yyyy"` formatted representation of the selected date:

```
String dobSource = datedob.getText().toString();
Date dobDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").parse(dobSource);
String dobTarget = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(dobDate);
```

You can potentially avoid converting the date string from the `TextView` by keeping track of a `Date` or `Calendar` reference that is updated whenever `onDateSet(...)` gets hit. That instance would then effectively become the data model backing the `TextView` and the value that ends up being inserted into the database.

That being said, personally I prefer to store/persist dates in their most elementary representation: as a `long` value. Such values are usually more easy to work with (as you avoid any parsing) and generally better interchangeable between various platforms. In the end, storing a date should be all about the actual data - any specific representation/format only complicates things further down the road.

Comment: So you are saying that pulling the date from onDateSet method would be better than pulling it from the TextView? If so, how would I pull it?

Comment: I think I already explained the gist of it in my answer above: create a `Calendar` instance that you update everytime new values come in through `onDateSet(...)`. You can then use that as backing data model for both the `TextView` and the value that eventually gets inserted into your database. Note that this is just the approach I would consider - it's not the *only* solution though. Up to you to decide on how to actually implement things.